# Smooth my scrolling TouchesMoved

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a semi-transparent view that sits above a table view. When I drag my view close to the bottom of the screen, I want to smoothly scroll the table view below it.

I'm trying to emulate:

User drags hover view near the bottom of the screen and holds it there.
Table view scrolls until they let go or until they reach the bottom of the table.
User lets go of the hover view.

Currently I'm doing:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!_hoverViewTouch) {
        return;
    }

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

    //scroll down.
    if (prevLocation.y < location.y) {
        if (location.y >= _table.frame.size.height - rowHeight) {
            NSArray *cells = [_table visibleCells];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [cells objectAtIndex:round(cells.count / 2)];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_table indexPathForCell:cell];
            [_table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:true];
        }
    }

    CGRect frame = [hoverView frame];
    frame.origin.y = location.y - (hoverView.frame.size.height / 2.0f);
    [hoverView setFrame:frame];
}
```

However, it scrolls so fast to the bottom of the table. How can I slow it down or smoothen the scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableView's scrollToRowAtIndexPath method doesn't give you any control over the animation speed. Instead, you can use a `CADisplayLink` to smoothly update the table view's `contentOffset`.

```
- (void)startAnimatingTable
{
    self.scrollStartDate = [NSDate date];
    self.startContentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkFired:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopAnimatingTable
{
    [self.displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)displayLinkFired:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    NSTimeInterval interval = -[self.scrollStartDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    CGFloat speed = 100;
    CGFloat yOffset = self.startContentOffset.y + speed * interval;
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.startContentOffset.x, yOffset);
}
```

Comment: At first I used an NSTimer in a long press gesture but that didn't work. I ended up using NSTimer schedule with interval 0.1 and scrolled the table 3 rows from the middle. Works extremely well but I'll most likely use your solution as I'll be able to use that `yOffset` calculation to move other views. I'll post my current solution in a bit.